# RESTful API with Spring MVC and GWT and overlay types

Tags: java, spring, rest, gwt, spring-mvc

I have developed a simple Spring MVC RESTful API and now I moved to the stage to create a simple GWT project to perform some requests to this api and obviously I choose that the communication will be done by exchanging JSON messages.

When receiving a response I will have to unmarshall it to a POJO.

I am aware that the general approach is to create the so called 'overlay types' but that looks to me as a mere duplicate of the java classes I wrote in api.

So the question is:
why shouldn't I simply create a common api that simply contains the common classes to perform this marshalling/unmarshalling?

I can clearly see that the main benefit is that if any change is needed you won't have to change also the overlay types.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you can define interfaces for your pojo, you can share those  Interfaces in client and server side (common package)

In server side you have to code your implementations which are used for the RESTful api.

In client side, the implementation of those interfaces can be done automatically with generators. For this you can use [gwtquery databinding](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding) or [gwt autobeans](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean).

To request your RESTful api, you can use either [gwtquery ajax](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax) or  [gwt requestbuilder](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html)

Each option has its advantages, normally I use gwtquery because its simplicity and because its databinding approach is more lightweight, otherwise, with autobeans you can create your POJOS using autobeans factories in both client and server sides. If you already have developed your backend this is not a goal for you though.

Answer (score 0):

The REST response can be consumed by any client and not specifically one client. If I understand your question correctly, you want to build the logic of marshalling and unmarshalling inside your REST API. Ideally it violates **Single Responsibility Principal.** You might need to change the mapping logic if the service changes so you are touching two different aspects of an API where as only one component requires change.

Also, the REST API should ideally be designed to be client agnostic. It is your specific requirement to translate them to POJO but another client might want to consume it as simple plain JSON. If you provide an overlay type, your code will be quite loosely coupled.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer Ashish.
I would like to add that I don't want to build the logic of marshalling/unmarshalling inside the REST, I just want to share the classes.
Let's say that the REST response is a List<Player> translated to JSON. Then in my client I want to reconstruct Java objects from it.
I don't see why that would make my REST not being client agnostic. It's the GWT client that will be built accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If your server side class (Player for example) can be serialized/desirialized without any problems, then you can send it to client side without any overlay type / conversion (serialization to JSON on server -> transport -> desirialization from JSON on client). On client side you can use RestyGWT for example to archieve automatic desirialization process.  Overlay types and conversion process are necessary only in the case when Player instance cannot be serialized (for example it is backed by Hibernate).